# Python - How do I get the window handle from my OWN application

Tags: python, winapi, pyqt, win32gui

I am using `win32gui`.
With `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` I am able to get the handle of any window, resize, setpos etc. but how am I able to grab my own windows handle? I was not able to identify it using FindWindow and passing the class or title. Is there any other way?

In this example print will just print `0`
(unrelated code removed)

```
import win32gui
import sys

class GUI(QMainWindow):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    
    super().__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi('window.ui', self)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = GUI()
    win.show()

    mywindow = win32gui.FindWindow("QMainWindow",None)
    print ("My Window: ",mywindow)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

from my window.ui xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>My App</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="QMainWindow">
[...]
```

**EDIT**: maybe winId()? But self.winId() and win.winId() return `<PyQt6.sip.voidptr object at 0x000002B0[...]`

Comment: `winId()` returns the window handle. It is typed as a `void*`, that's why you're getting the output you're seeing. The value `0x2b0` is the window handle.

Comment: @IInspectable I got it, I just converted it to int :) Do you know why it didn't work with the w32 FindWindow method? Is it only possible to identify other windows and not your own with that method?

Comment: You can use `FindWindow` to find *any* top-level window, so long as you pass the correct window class name. You can use a tool like Spy++ to discover the window class name. I don't know whether Qt uses a static class name, or invents unique ones at run time.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it**

```
[...]
winhandle = int(win.winId())
print("My Window: ",winhandle)
```

Still curious why it didn't work with FindWindow
**edit**: found out that PyQt Standart Window Class is `MainWindow` , without the Q.

So `mywindow = win32gui.FindWindow("MainWindow",None)` without the Q works.

Comment: The `ClassName` argument is a *window class*, not the Qt class used in development (of which Windows has absolutely no knowledge).